How can you calculate Q1 and Q3 for even numbers?
I've searched this question everywhere, but I've found different answers and none of them result in the same answer Numpy gave me.
I have the following data:[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 8]
When using numpy.percentile for 25(Q1) and 75(Q3), I get the following answer: 2.25 and 5.0.
However, I couldn't replicate this formula. For instance, when looking at this post, the answer should be the center of each half of the data, which would result in Q1 = 2 and Q3 = 5.
If following this other post, the answer would be Q1 = 2.75 and Q3 = 5.25.
I have no clue on which answer is correct and which formula numpy is using.

This is the result given for type=7 by the R quantile function described in the duplicate.

... while Q1=2 and Q3=5 are given by types 1, 2 or 5; none of the types give Q1=2.75, though type 6 gives Q1=1.75 and Q3=5.25.
